# Unity, OnMouseOver blocked by another gameobject with a collider in front of it

Tags: unity

I have two gameobjects, both with 2D colliders.

One of them can be behind the other, and because of this its OnMouseOver can be blocked from firing as the GameObject in front blocks it from triggering.

What is a way around this? I really like the ease of using OnMouseOver, and would rather not use raycastAll.

Asked this question on SO, maybe it should be asked here.

Comment: Please [don't cross post](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/cross-posting-programming-questions-on-stackoverflow-and-gamedev-stackexchange). ([So question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862205/unity-onmouseover-blocked-by-another-gameobject-with-a-collider-in-front-of-it))

Comment: I have asked this before maybe it will helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465363/restricting-onmousedown-event-on-specific-collides

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's a cross post from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862205/unity-onmouseover-blocked-by-another-gameobject-with-a-collider-in-front-of-it). Please chose the best site for your question and ask it only there.

Comment: Ok I will do that from now on. Sorry for the crosspost.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways of doing that.

A classic, manual `Raycast` (recommended):

```
 void Update () 
 {
     RaycastHit[] hits = Physics.RaycastAll(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition));
     foreach(RaycastHit hit in hits)
     {
         if(hit.collider.gameObject.name == "Cube A")
         {
             //do something here
             break;
         }
     }
 }
```

The second one involves setting your object's layer to `Ignore Raycast`, which should work perfectly with `OnMouseOver`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

Only option I can think of rn is using a 2nd camera that only renders clickable objects, so the objects that would block the ray are somewhere else in the world but rendered on another cam with higher/lower depth.

But it would probably be easier to make a ray with a LayerMask at that point.